# How do I overwrite the value of a specific index/column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe `Exposure` with zeros constructed as follows:

```
Exposure = pd.DataFrame(0, index=dates, columns=tickers)
```

and a DataFrame `df` with data.

I want to fill some of the data from `df` to `Exposure`:

```
    for index, column in df.iterrows():
        # value of df(index,column) to be filled at Exposure(index,column)
```

How do I overwrite the value of at `(index,column)` of `Exposure` with the value of `df(index,column)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for index, column in df.iterrows():
    Exposure.loc[index, column.index] = column.values
```

This will make new index and columns in *Exposure* if they don't exist, if you want to avoid this, construct the common index and columns firstly, then do the assignment in a vectorized way(avoiding the for loop):

```
common_index = Exposure.index.intersection(df.index)
common_columns = Exposure.columns.intersection(df.columns)
Exposure.loc[common_index, common_columns] = df.loc[common_index, common_columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is:

```
df.loc[index, column] = value
```

Comment: according to pandas themselves, this is the preferred method, as dataframe[rows, columns] is not typesafe